# How to resize DirectX window efficiently?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, directx

I looked at this site example: http://www.codesampler.com/dx9src/dx9src_6.htm

But the code is rather weird: it frees every texture, vertex buffer, everything! and then builds them up again: loads the model from disk ... i dont think that is very efficient! OpenGL can do window resizing on fly with no such limitations. How can i do the same as OpenGL does: efficient window resize with no need to free every resource in my program?

I tried the code in the above link example, without those invalidateDeviceObjects/restoreDeviceObjects function calls, but it didnt work.. so i guess it must be done? I hope not, or window resizing would be a pain on larger apps where you have hundreds of megabytes of data allocated in textures, models etc.

Comment: you have to flush resources to redraw on a resized window. do as the reference said.

Comment: @Uğur Gümüşhan, does this apply on pop-up window (not fullscreen) too? im sure ive seen programs like that which allows real-time window resizing without lag.

Comment: yes, also because you can't resize fullscreen either (laughs). those programs are either use GDI or some other libraries, not directx. of course you can resize, but this would involve resource flush, as I said.

Comment: be sure you are using the right event for the operation, like mouse release, it will cause problems if you handle resizing and device reset on mouse move

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a consequence of how d3d9 was designed.  Resizing a d3d9 window requires a call to [IDirect3DDevice9::Reset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174425%28VS.85%29.aspx), and from the docs:

> Calling IDirect3DDevice9::Reset causes all texture memory surfaces to be lost, managed textures to be flushed from video memory, and all state information to be lost.

So it is what it is.  You don't actually customarily *change* the resolution of the display, at all, ever, from game start to game end.  Usually you set the resolution on game start, allow resetting in some special settings screen.

Now I should add, if you are using D3D9, there is a special resource allocation flag you can use ([D3DPOOL_MANAGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172584%28VS.85%29.aspx)) that will actually take care of re-loading resources *for you*.  So a local (system memory) copy of all textures, vertex buffers, etc is *automatically* maintained in system memory, and when the GPU is reset, those textures etc are automatically copied back down to the GPU.

Keep in mind `D3DPOOL_MANAGED` isn't allowed if you're using the newer `IDirect3DDevice9Ex`.

Comment: So, my program is in windowed mode, how do i resize the window without freeing all my resources? Im pretty sure ive seen this behaviour on some other directx windowed apps before... and there was no lag or delay when i resized those windows :S in fact, those apps resized in real time: i could see the screen stretch. so it couldnt reload the stuff every frame...

Comment: Yes, you can change the _window_ size without changing the screen _resolution_.  You just have to use [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534(VS.85).aspx) or [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: You can also resize the area of what is being drawn using [Viewport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174469(VS.85).aspx) settings

Answer (score 3):

In a non-game business application where frequent resizing windows was an important part of the UI, I worked around this issue by creating the D3D device as a memory device at the detected full-screen resolution, then used StretchBlt in the CWnd::OnDraw(...) to resize the memory bitmap as it was being written from the backbuffer to the screen.  This isn't a good solution for high frame rate animation, but in a relatively static view situation where the user's actions control the object/view motion it works better than the tear-down and recreate approach.

Comment: so basically you created full-screen size pixel memory for the app, but only displayed some of it to the user? it was still rendering it in fullscreen? doesnt sound like ive seen it done on some apps...

Answer (score 1):

Create the back buffer to be the monitor's max resolution, and use `SWAPEFFECT_COPY`.

When drawing, have your code draw to the current window size.

When calling `Present`, provide the window size for the source and destination rectangles.

Then you have a resizable window that doesn't need to recreate the D3D device when the window size changes.