# Changing resolution in DirectX9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I'm finding it hard to find good sources of information for explanations of DirectX API although I've been looking at the DirectX Documentation for a while.

I'm trying to create a method for a wrapper class for DX9 that changes the resolution during runtime. I've managed to handle this with DirectDraw but I find no information regarding DX9 even though it should be more common.

All I found was a reference to SetDisplayMode, but neither my Direct Object or my DirectX Device has this method.

I'm using DirectX 9.

Example method:

```
void SetResolution(int width, int height, int depth)
{
   // I have access to DirectX device, object and the window HWND in this class
};
```

...do I change the HWND window size, or do I handle this in DirectX? I know how to change resolution in a Windows application but no clue how to do it in DX9.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize DirectX window efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764013/how-to-resize-directx-window-efficiently)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adjusting your D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS the way you normally would. Something like:

```
// D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS is already defined as md3dPP
RECT R ={0, 0, 640, 480}
AdjustwindowRect(&R, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);
md3dPP.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
md3dPP.BackBufferWidth = 640;
md3dPP.BackBufferHeight = 480;
md3dPP.Windowed = true;
```

If you wish, this might also be a good time to change the window style, such as:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(yourWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW)

// must use SetWindowPos for SetWindowLongPtr changes to take effect
SetWindowPos(yourWindowHandle, HWND_TOP, 100, 100, R.right, R.bottom, SWP_NOZORDER |     SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Alternatively, if you're using fullscreen:

```
md3dPP.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
md3dPP.BackBufferWidth = 640;
md3dPP.BackBufferHeight = 480;
md3dPP.Windowed = true;

SetWindowLongPtr(yourWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP)

// must use SetWindowPos for SetWindowLongPtr changes to take effect
SetWindowPos(yourWindowHandle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 640, 480, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Either way, follow this up by calling IDirect3DDevice9::Reset. Just make sure you re-initialize your resources when resetting.

So if you defined something like:    IDirect3DDevice9 *gd3dDevice;

Use:

```
gd3dDevice->Reset(&md3dPP);
```

Comment: I have something exactly like this, but calling Reset fails each time and the screen goes blank - I have to create a new device each time.

Answer (score 1):

When creating an `IDirect3DDevice9` the resoltuion will be set using the `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` and the front buffer will be allocated. You cannot change the size of the buffer without recreating the entire device or calling [IDirect3DDevice9::Reset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174425%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: All I get after setting a new D3DPRESENT_PARAMETER and calling Reset() on the device is a white screen, even though I clear the background color to blue each draw.

Comment: Also I set a hotkey to enable/disable fullscreen, but after a few times it just stops responding.