# How to change screen resolution in DirectX 9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I'm trying to write a program using DirectX 9. As a part of this program I need a way to change screen resolution i.e. height and width for the DirectX device. I have a pointer to my `LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9` stored, and I need a function that looks like this:

```
void SetResolution(int x, int y) {
// some code that actually changes the resolution
}
```

Surprisingly, I failed to find it on the internet. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278502/changing-resolution-in-directx9) thread on this site, but the accepted answer is very vague and looks like a mix of WinAPI and DirectX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recreate the device and pass updated params (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172588(v=vs.85).aspx)

It means you need to reload all your resources onto the graphics card though.